# Adding NSOperation with Dependencies after a For Loop

Tags: ios, facebook, multithreading, graph, nsoperation

So I'm trying to execute `lastOperation` after all the block operations, but for some reason it is being executed first. Why is this? Is adding dependencies the wrong way to do it?

```
[self facebookAccount:^(NSError *error, ACAccount *facebookAccount) {
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    NSBlockOperation *lastOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:completionAll];
    for (NSString *postID in postIDs) {
        NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            NSString *postIDString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/%@", postID];
            NSURL *postIDURL = [NSURL URLWithString:postIDString];
            SLRequest *postIDRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:postIDURL parameters:nil];
            postIDRequest.account = facebookAccount;

            [postIDRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                NSError *parseError;
                NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&parseError];

                completion(response);
            }];

        }];
        [queue addOperation:operation];
        [lastOperation addDependency:operation];
    }

    [queue addOperation:lastOperation];

}];
```

If I add the following code inside the [self facebookAccount:^(NSError *error, ACAccount *facebookAccount)]:

```
[RACObserve(queue, operationCount) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        NSLog(@"Operation count for queue: %@", x);
    }];
```

then the output to console is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5akr.png (sorry I can't post pictures, but I'll get my reputation up soon)

And the position of the "all done" varies around between 5 and 10 usually. So I'm pretty sure that it depends on which NSOperations finish processing the GET request before the queue gets to the lastOperation.

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question but do you have more than one post?

Comment: Have you tried to set the dependency before adding the operations to the queue? Can't say why it doesn't work but I would try to refactor and see if it works. Then try to learn from that.

Comment: One thing to try is to add all the post blocks to a single block operation as they will be executed and the operation only considered finished when all the blocks are finished. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSBlockOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Can you make it more clear what you are expecting to see? Put some NSLog calls in the code like NSLog(@"1"); and tell us in what order you are seeing them and in what order did you want to see them.

Comment: Yeah sorry, so what this code is doing is adding a bunch of NSOperations which make GET requests and process the response to an NSOperationQueue. I want to know when the NSOperationQueue has not only finished making the GET requests, but finished processing them as well. The processing is not included in this question, but it is the block 'completion(response)' and what it does is store the parsed 'response' in a Core Data entity. The block 'completionAll()' is what is what should be called when everything is done. I did try to add the dependencies before the operations, but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, not more than one post yet, what does that mean?

Comment: I'll edit the code a bit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing `performRequestWithHandler:` returns immediately, since it takes a callback block as its argument. As soon as the block for an NSBlockOperation returns, the operation is considered finished, so all your operations finish immediately and only later are their completion blocks called.

You might need to subclass NSOperation and implement the concurrent methods (minimum: `start`, `isConcurrent`, `isExecuting`, and `isFinished`) instead of the non-concurrent methods (minimum: `main`). The callback from `performRequestWithHandler:` should trigger a key-value notification for state-related properties to indicate the NSOperation is finished.

Comment: So if I make it that my operation isExecuting while it performs whatever is in the callback, and then isFinished accordingly, NSOperationQueue will automatically wait until the isFinished signal to move onto the next operation? Keeping my setMaxConcurrentOperationCount to 1 should do this right? If so, I think that's a really helpful comment, thanks!

Comment: Absolutely, and I can second this as well; it's worked out for me in my codebases that I've worked on. Additionally, subclassing `NSOperation` and structuring the code this way gives me clean "units of work" that I can then toss about as needed (or chain together). Plus, while I believe you can give a block operation an `NSString` name representation, subclassing `NSOperation` gives a much cleaner appearance to your code when debugging, especially all the way down in a stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I needed. I'll update this once I get it working, but it seems like a fairly straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

NSOperations get their -start method called as soon as they are added to an NSOperationQueue. So each operation inside the for-loop gets kicked off when you call [queue addOperation:operation];

Since lastOperation has operation set as a dependency, it will get called each time those operations complete, which likely is occurring before you add lastOperation to queue.

Comment: So I'm using ReactiveCocoa for key-value observing, and I'm observing the operationCount of the NSOperationQueue and NSLogging everything that's sent. In my completionAll() which is the block of the lastOperation I just NSLog("all done"). I've edited my post to show you what it looks like.